# Why is it advised to cache getBudget()?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I've seen a slide which advises to cache with a dictionary. In which case we can even get the same budget twice? What does it save?

[image]

The API docs state that:

```
getBudget()
Returns the budget of the campaign. In order to change the campaign's budget,
```

Answer (score 0):

The map isn't used to cache the budgets, it's to avoid doubling the same budget more than once.

If you were to remove that part of the code, a budget that is *shared by multiple campaigns* would be doubled the number of times it is used in an individual campaign (e.g. if a budget is used in 3 campaigns, it would be increased eightfold after you run the script).